# asp.net GridView ImageField set DataImageUrlField result of linq join

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, gridview

I have a GridView built in this way:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gridView" class="table table-striped table-bordered gvs" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="gridView_RowDataBound">
   <Columns>                    
    <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="a.ProfilePicture" HeaderText="Img"></asp:ImageField>                
    <asp:BoundField runat="server" HeaderText="Name" DataField="a.Name"/>   
...
```

I load data into my GridView in this way:

```
gridView.DataSource=GetData();
gridView.DataBind();
```

The method `GetData` returns a List using Linq:

```
public static List<dynamic> GetData()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var context = new Entities())
            {
                var entities = (from a in context.Artist
                                join s in context.List_StatusType on a.Type equals s.Code
                                where s.Table == "Artist" && s.Field == "Type" 
                                select new { a, Tipo = s.Value }).ToList<dynamic>();
                return entities;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

when I go to my page, the application gives me a `DataBind` Error:

> System.Web.HttpException: Impossible find field or property 'a.ProfilePicture'

---

Instead,
If I Bound fields in this way, all works perfectly.

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gridView" class="table table-striped table-bordered gvs" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="gridView_RowDataBound">
   <Columns>                    
    <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="Immagine" HeaderText="Img"></asp:ImageField>                
    <asp:BoundField runat="server" HeaderText="Name" DataField="a.Name"/>   
...

public static List<dynamic> GetData()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var context = new Entities())
            {
                var entities = (from a in context.Artist
                                join s in context.List_StatusType on a.Type equals s.Code
                                where s.Table == "Artist" && s.Field == "Type" 
                                select new { a, Immagine=a.ProfilePicture, Tipo = s.Value }).ToList<dynamic>();
                return entities;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

What problem is this? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not switch to `TemplateField`. It gives you more control. Then you can bind a complete list to the GridView.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Img">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Artist.ProfilePicture") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Note that the Eval shows the namespace of the nested class itself, not the name of the property in the parent class.

And since you are working with `List`, I reccomend switching to a strongly typed GridView. See my answer here: [How to list data retrieved from a table in Aspx page web form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45795782/how-to-list-data-retrieved-from-a-table-in-aspx-page-web-form/). Then you have access to all the properties as you would in code behind.

Answer (score 0):

The ImageField is less tolerant of the nested properties. In your first example, you are projecting with `select new { a, Tipo = s.Value }` which is creating an anonymous object (dynamic) in your case with a property called `Tipo`, but crucially, another property called `a` which is an `Artist` object with properties of its own in a `dynamic`. So to access `a`, you would need to say `a.ProfilePicture`, whereas for `Imagine`, in your second example that's a top level property that you projected as `select new { a, Immagine=a.ProfilePicture, Tipo = s.Value }`.

You can project all the properties you need at the top level like:
var entities = (from a in context.Artist
        join s in context.List_StatusType on a.Type equals s.Code
        where s.Table == "Artist" && s.Field == "Type"
        select new
        {
            a.ProfilePicture,
            a.Name,
            Tipo = s.Value
        }).ToList();

A better approach would be to create a view model with the properties you want for your GridView to remove ambiguity and return a collection of that model instead of dynamic.

```
public class ArtistViewModel
{
    public string ProfilePicture { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Tipo { get; set; }
    // ... and so on
}
```

Then in your GetData() method return

```
var entities = (from a in context.Artist
    join s in context.List_StatusType on a.Type equals s.Code
    where s.Table == "Artist" && s.Field == "Type"
    select new ArtistViewModel
    {
        ProfilePicture= a.ProfilePicture,
        Name = a.Name,
        Tipo = s.Value
    }).ToList();
```